# The process cannot access the file 'E:\test.txt' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to remove out-of-sequence `white spaces` from a text file to `one-space` sequence in a winForm i.e.,

**From**

```
sagchjvcsj    kbschjsdchs      sudbjsdbl
sdvbchjbvsdjc    kbsadcsadk    kskbjdsdcksajdbc
```

**To**

```
sagchjvcsj kbschjsdchs sudbjsdbl
sdvbchjbvsdjc kbsadcsadk kskbjdsdcksajdbc
```

My implementation is:

```
private void buttonBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stream myStream;
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialogImage = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialogImage.Filter = "Text files | .txt";
            openFileDialogImage.Multiselect = false;

            if (openFileDialogImage.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialogImage.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    textBoxFileName.Text = openFileDialogImage.FileName;
                }
            }
        }              

    private void buttonGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = textBoxFileName.Text;
            string s = string.Empty;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path, true))
            {
                s = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            string[] parts = s.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
            string pathSave = saveFileDialog.FileName;
            File.CreateText(pathSave);
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pathSave))
            {
                sw.Write(parts);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error that I am getting on line `using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pathSave))` is:

```
The process cannot access the file 'E:\test.txt' because it is being used by another process.
```

I downloaded ProcessWorker to see which process is currently locking `Test.txt` but I don't see any process using it. Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: is your path and pathSave is the same test.txt file?

Comment: @Dr.Stitch No. `path` is when you upload the original file. `pathSave` is when you `Create` a new file. It is upto you to keep the name same or changed.

Comment: the error you're saying might occur if the user select the same path for opendialog and savedalog. that's why i'm asking if the path is the same.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other suggestions, your problem is that `File.CreateText()` will lock so you need to release the lock. I have wrapped the call to `File.CreateText()` in a using statement to release the lock.

There was an issue with the output of the StreamWriter so I made some changes to get the expected output as per your question.

```
private void buttonGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = textBoxFileName.Text;
    string s = string.Empty;
    string[] parts;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path, true))
    {
        parts = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    }

    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
    string pathSave = saveFileDialog.FileName;

    using (File.CreateText(pathSave))
    { }

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pathSave))
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        foreach (string s in parts)
        {
            result += s + " ";
        }
        sw.Write(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it has solved the situation. Thanks alot. If i change the name to a new name in `SaveFileDialog`, it is saving file as a `text file` but is opening it with `WebMatrix`. Any ideas why?

Comment: I don't know why it is opening with WebMatrix. WebMatrix is not a technology that I am familiar with.

Comment: OK. When `OpenFileDialog` opens, window doesn't show .txt files in it. How come?

Comment: saveFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*" ;

Comment: Add this before you call saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();

Comment: Tim. Adding`saveFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (.txt)|.txt|All files (.)|*.*" ;` before calling `saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();` has done the magic. :) Thanks a lot friend.

Comment: Above code works fine with small size text files, but when I run it on a bigger sized file like I am running it now on a 54MB text file, this program is not only taking very long (more than 60 minutes so far) but is also not giving any output and freezes saying (Not Responding). Not sure if its actually working on processing the file or has actually frozen. Any ideas why?

Comment: Hi Rehan, I think that is a new and different question from your original. It might be worth posting a new question for the answer.